# Unknown type name while known?

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode has showed out of the blue this error: "Unknown type name"

I'll explain:
My StoriesViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Stories.h"

@interface StoriesViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>

@property (strong) Stories *story; //Here it goes- "Unknown type name `Stories`"
@property (weak) IBOutlet UITextView *storyView;
@end
```

In my Stories.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface Stories : UIDocument


@property (strong) NSString * storyContent;

@end
```

Again, out of the blue.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

In my ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Stories.h"
#import "StoriesViewController.h"
#import "StoriesPickerViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate,  UIAlertViewDelegate> {

}


@end
```

NB @class throws loads of ARC issues.

I have removed useless references to ViewController.h, worked.
SOLVED!

Answer (score 13):

You have a [circular reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference) problem.

What's happening is that when you load your `ViewController` it goes through it's imports, it loads `Stories.h`, it goes to load it's imports and it goes back to `ViewController.h`, so you are stuck in an infinite loop there.

Either remove one of the conflicting imports, or use [forward class declaration](http://www-subatech.in2p3.fr/~photons/subatech/soft/carnac/CPP-INC-1.shtml) (that example is for C++, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862717/can-anyone-give-example-of-forward-declaration-in-objective-c-for-a-normal-class) for an example with Objective-C)

Comment: Again, @class throws lots of errors when using properties. Is there a way to solve it using #import?

Comment: can't you remove the `#import "ViewController.h"` in `Stories`? what are you using it for? what errors does it throw when using `@class`?

Comment: You are awesome..I was frustrated with this error.. Thanks a  lot

Answer (score 0):

After so many hours spending I found that, I have imported a some files in .h header file which was causing the import recursion.

> How I fixed - I moved the same import in .m file and the build is
> successful.
>
> Suggestion - Avoid class implementation imports in .h file.

Hope this helps!