# Where is NSTextField?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextfield, iboutlet

I'm brand new to Mac OS X development. Primarily a Java and C# developer.
I'm reading this book and trying a few examples from the book.

In my AppController class, I'm trying to add an `IBOutlet` as follows :

```
IBOutlet NSTextField *textField;
```

It gives me an error saying "Unknown type name 'NSTextField'.
I have imported Foundation/Foundation.h

Please help.

Comment: #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
can u see this in your AppController header file ? and do consider reading the answer to this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12283685/unknown-type-name-while-known

Comment: @NofelMahmood Adding #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h> fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: @NofelMahmood Yes. Go ahead and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
```

Import this in your AppController header file